# Error in adding new item to my database using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been getting this error while submiting a form using codeigniter. I need help even though I have been following the documentation.
I am using 2.x version of codeigniter

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Products::$input‐

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 52


Fatal error: Call to undefined function post() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/gamingplace/application/models/product_model.php on line 63
```

This is the code in my model

```
 //add new product
        public function addProduct(){
          $data = array(
            'category_id' => $this->input‐>post('category_id'),
            'title' => $this->input‐>post('title'),
            'description' => $this->input‐>post('description'),
            'price' => $this->input‐>post('price')
          );
          if($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0){
            $data['image'] = $this->upload->file_name;
            return $this->db->insert('products',$data);
            }
          }
        }
```

This is the code in my controller

```
public function addProduct()
{
  if($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0){
    //setting  image preferences
    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|PNG|JPEG|JPG';
    $config['overwrite'] = false;
    $config['quality'] = '100%';
    $config['remove_spaces'] = true;
    $config['max_size']  = '90';// in KB
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    echo $this->input->post('image');

    if( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))
    {
      $this->session->set_flashdata('message_failed', $this->upload->display_errors('', ''));
      redirect('dashboard');
    }else{
    //Image Resizing
    $config['source_image'] = $this->upload->upload_path.$this->upload->file_name;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config['width'] = 311;
    $config['height'] = 162;
    $this->load->library('image_lib',$config);
    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize()){
      $this->session->set_flashdata('message_failed', $this->image_lib->display_errors('', ''));
    }
    //calling a model an its method to add a new product to the database
    if($this->product_model->addProduct()){
      $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
      $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'A new product,'. $upload_data['file_name'].'has been added!');
    redirect('dashboard');
  }
}
}
}
}
```

And my view

```
<!-- Modal -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/validation.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <div class="modal fade" id="addProduct" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add Product</h4> <em>if the product category is not in the select option,
               go to add category link to add category before adding this product</em>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <?php echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">','</div>') ?>
              <form role= "form" action="<?php echo base_url()?>products/addProduct" method="post" name="form" onsubmit="return validate(this)" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name of product" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Brief Description of Product</label>
                <textarea name="description" rows="8" cols="80" class="form-control">
                  This is a brand made by Gucci Company. Made of cotton, bla bla bla
                </textarea>
              </div>
              <label>Select Category</label>
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" name="category_id">
                  <?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $popular): ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo$popular->id?>"><?php echo $popular->name ?></option>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Enter or choose price</label>
                <input type="number" id="price" class="form-control"  name="price_old" required>
              </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="price" class="form-control" id="mainPrice"required>
             <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control" required  accept="image/*" onChange="validateImage(this.value)">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class=" form-control btn  btn-success">Add</button>
            </form>
          </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where are you loading the Products model?  Is it an autoload or in the construct of the controller?  Also, you aren't actually passing the post into the model function for addProduct().

Comment: Do you use same function to trigger view and receive data ??

Comment: @cfnerd, I use the autoload. I am still  a beginner but was trying to build something with it and now stuck due to the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a few issues going on with your code, but let's first focus on your question/error you mentioned.  In your controller function, you are not passing the post to the model.  You need to do something like this in the controller:

```
$addProduct = $this->product_model->addProduct($_POST);

if($addProduct){
    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'A new product,'. $upload_data['file_name'].'has been added!');
    redirect('dashboard');
}
```

In the model function, you need to first let the function know there is an incoming parameter, then adjust how you are assigning the fields to the data array.

```
public function addProduct($post){
    $data = array(
        'category_id' =>    $post["category_id"],
        'title' =>          $post["title"],
        'description' =>    $post["description"],
        'price' =>          $post["price"]
    );

    return $this->db->insert('products',$data);
}
```

---

After that, I noticed that you have some other FILES logic in your model.  That will likely error out, too.  I believe that is going to have to be done in the controller, not the model.  Once you do the upload in the controller, you can pass the file name into the model as well.

```
$upload_data = $this->upload->data();
$addProduct = $this->product_model->addProduct($_POST, $upload_data['file_name']);

if($addProduct){
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'A new product,'. $upload_data['file_name'].'has been added!');
    redirect('dashboard');
}
```

Then, adjust the model.

```
public function addProduct($post, $fileName){
    $data = array(
        'category_id' =>    $post["category_id"],
        'title' =>          $post["title"],
        'description' =>    $post["description"],
        'price' =>          $post["price"],
        'image' =>          $fileName
    );

    return $this->db->insert('products',$data);
}
```

Hope this helps.